# How do I use reflection with AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android

I'm creating an Alert dialog by using the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

With Android 3.0, alert dialogs inherit the theme of the activity that created them.  You can override this action by creating the alert dialog with this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
```

(More on that **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)**)

Unfortunately this force-closes on previous versions of Android.  I assume using reflection is the answer, but I can't figure out the syntax no matter how much I read.  Can anybody provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I assume using reflection is the answer, but I can't figure out the syntax no matter how much I read.

You could perhaps use reflection. I wouldn't.

I'd go with `HoneycombHelper`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC) also has a situation where it needs to do different things for 3.0 versus not -- in this case, work with a custom `View` in the action bar. You can't call `getActionView()` on a `MenuItem` pre-3.0.

So, where I need the custom `View`, I do this:

```
    EditText add=null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        View v=HoneycombHelper.getAddActionView(menu);

        if (v!=null) {
            add=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    if (add!=null) {
        add.setOnEditorActionListener(onSearch);
    }
```

Here, I bury the `getActionView()` call in a static method of a `HoneycombHelper` class:

```
class HoneycombHelper {
    static View getAddActionView(Menu menu) {
        return(menu.findItem(R.id.add).getActionView());
    }
}
```

I only ever load `HoneycombHelper` on 3.0 or higher, so even though it contains invalid method calls for older versions of Android, it's not a problem.

In your case, your `HoneycombHelper` would have a `gimmeMyBuilderDammit()` method, or some such, that uses the API Level 11 constructor.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  For future readers, my HoneycombHelper looks like this: `import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;

class HoneycombHelper
{
 static AlertDialog.Builder getBuilder(Context context)
 {
  return(new AlertDialog.Builder(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK));
 }
}` and to call it: `AlertDialog.Builder builder;if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      builder = HoneycombHelper.getBuilder(context);
     }
     else
     {
      builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     }`

Comment: @wirbly: Glad it worked for you! Even if you didn't name the method `gimmeMyBuilderDammit()`... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare I've been using reflection so far. It's very messy. Using a wrapper type class to group newer API specific functions seems more elegant. Any drawbacks to using this as opposed to reflection? Also I assume you should add all new Honeycomb functions that you'll be using in the same `HoneycombHelper` class correct (as opposed to making several helper classes)?

Comment: @Turbo: "Any drawbacks to using this as opposed to reflection?" -- not IMHO. Also note that `HoneycombHelper` is only needed if you are still supporting Android 1.x. If you are only supporting Android 2.x and higher, you can reference new API methods just fine, so long as you use `Build` to prevent executing those statements on older devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare I indeed am still supporting 1.6. However, I think you just blew my mind with using `Build` to do the version check on 2.x and higher. I noticed this behavior before, but was never sure about it. Does the version specific code get stripped out when compiling or was there a change to the DVM or something to prevent loading of not-yet-existant functions?

Comment: @Turbo: In 1.x, as soon as Dalvik would load a class that referenced something not recognizable, it would fail with a `VerifyError`. Starting with Android 2.0, Dalvik waits to throw the `VerifyError` until you actually *use* the thing that it can't find. So, if you route around the missing stuff using `Build`, you're golden.

Comment: @CommonsWare that sounds much better. I just tried looking for a mention of it in the official docs, but can't find anything. For future reference do you know where I can find such news?

Comment: @Turbo: I know a nice book that covers it. :-) Beyond that, this came up in past stuff here and on the android-developers Google Group. I forget if there was an Android Developers Blog post that mentioned it or not.